# in java using vtd-xml throws java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, xml-parsing, vtd-xml

I have an ear app with two EJB and one WEB (war) projects all using compiler compliance 1.5. In my web project I created a utility Class file that takes a byte array of an xml file and returns some string values using the vtd-xml library v2.10 and I instantiate an object of this class in a servlet. At the call of the constructor of the object (that takes a byte array) I get the error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
```

When I remove all vtd-xml related objects from the class I do not get this error. Any advice would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can recompile using the build.bat file (included with vtd-xml.zip) to obtain a new vtd-xml.jar.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the vtd-xml jar file has classes in it that are 1.6

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError.html) says:

> Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine attempts to read a class file and determines that the major and minor version numbers in the file are not supported.

The library you are using must have been compiled with a different version of Java.

Answer (score 2):

Now it works executing build.bat file (included with vtd-xml.zip) but you need to edit the target version to 1.5 instead of 1.6